# how to use IEnumerator as I am having some errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting an error as "The type or namespace name 'IEnumerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS0246)." The problem comes in IEnumerator

Does anyone know how to solve it the code is as follows :

````
public Text txt;    

IEnumerator wait()
    {
        txt.enabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        txt.enabled = false;
    }


    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(wait());
    }```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `IEnumerator` namespace.
As the compiler tells you, you need to add a `using` directive on top of your code:

`using System.Collections;`

Comment: Thank you I was having a look at brackeys video and he told when using IEnumerator you should have system.collections; but still thank you for your help